# Why does the following code display the warning 'literal suffix identifiers that do not start with an underscore are reserved'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, operators, operator-keyword

Why does the following code display the warning 'literal suffix identifiers that do not start with an underscore are reserved' in only one invocation of the operator. The ""ms operator is not user-defined, so why does the system initially think that it is? This was compiled with MSVC 2019.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    std::chrono::duration<double> dur = std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""ms((unsigned long long)1);
    using namespace std::chrono_literals; //this line displays the warning,
    std::chrono::duration<double> dur2 = 1ms; //but this one does not
    std::cout << dur.count() << std::endl;
}
```

Edit: I'm using C++17: __cplusplus is defined with 201703L

[Live Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PEWjEb8K4)

Comment: It is a very unusual way to write things down so it might be a compiler bug. Yes compiler bugs happen too.

Comment: Which C++ version are you using? And are you confused about the error message or about the literal suffix not being defined?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Happens with `/std:c++14`, `/std:c++17`, and `/std:c++20`.

Comment: Reproduces on godbolt too (for msvc), gcc seems happy

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Both. I understand why this error would appear if I attempted to define my own literal operator, but ""ms is system-defined.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT: But no UDL is being *defined* here; it is simply being called via `operator""` syntax. I suspect the compiler implements C4455 by just looking for any sequence of tokens of the form `operator""name` and giving a warning if `name` doesn't start with an underscore outside of standard library headers.

Comment: Hi,I suggest you report this issue to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=62&entry=problem), it will be fixed in the future.